# i'am trying to make a function that deletes vowels in a string

Tags: python-3.x, list, definition

```
def disemvowel(word):
    new_word = []
    list_of_letter = list(word)

    for letter in list_of_letter:       
        if letter == 'a' or 'A' or 'E' or 'e' or 'O' or 'o' or 'U' or 'u':
           continue
        else:
            new_word.append(letter)

    return ''.join(new_word)
```

Comment: don't forget to include 'i' or 'I'. Also what's the problem?

Comment: `''.join([letter for letter in word if letter not in "AEIOUaeiou"])`

Comment: thank you very much,  just solved the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is always True
You should change it to:

```
if letter in "aAeEiIoOuU":
```

When you write

```
if letter == 'a' or 'A'
```

You said "if letter is 'a' or if 'A' is not a empty string", and a is not a empty string.